# Invoke an AWS Lambda Function without being Authenticated

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to invoke an AWS Lambda Function (using Python) without being authenticated, like so:

```
from boto3 import client 
from botocore import UNSIGNED
from botocore.client import Config
from json import dumps

def invoke(functionName, params):
    lambda_client = client('lambda', 
                    aws_access_key_id='', 
                    aws_secret_access_key='', 
                    config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED),
                    region_name="us-east-2")

    response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName=functionName,
                     Payload=bytes(dumps(params), encoding='utf8'))
    return response["Payload"].read()
```

The above code will run into a Missing Authentication Token error (403?), however. The Lambda function is set up with a resource-based policy statement and role that allows FunctionURLPublicAccess, but I'm guessing that I need something else to indicate that any unauthenticated user can invoke this function.

Another way of solving this would be to invoke the Function URL instead, but I'm not finding any documentation on how to do that in Python. Looking into either way would be super helpful, thank you!

EDIT:
Trying Gamze's FunctionURL code below, I am running into an Internal Server Error (502). Below is what I set for my lambda function policies:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnI96.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k70UK.png

I'm unsure if I need an API Gateway, and I don't think I do for this, but I have a template Lambda one setup as well.

Answer (score 2):

If your function is set to use `FunctionURLPublicAccess`, you should use regular python tools for HTTP requests, not `boto3`. So you have to modify your code to use, for example, [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) or python's own [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke an AWS Lambda function, you can use the requests library in Python to make HTTP requests directly to the Lambda function endpoint:
(Replace "YOUR_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_URL" with the actual URL of your Lambda function. This URL can be obtained from the AWS Lambda console.)

```
import requests
from json import dumps
    
    def invoke_lambda_function(lambda_url, params):
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    
        response = requests.post(lambda_url, headers=headers, data=dumps(params))
    
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.text
        else:
            # Handle errors appropriately
            print(f"Error: {response.status_code}\n{response.text}")
            return None
    
# Example usage
lambda_url = "YOUR_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_URL"
response = invoke_lambda_function(lambda_url, {"key": "value"})
    
if response is not None:
    print(response)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer which looks good. Additionally, you could provide official documentation reference as this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html, and also give some answers regarding the first part of the question where the user tries to invoke the lambda via boto3.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Gamze! I did try invoking the Function URL with the code you provided me, but I'm now running into an Internal Server Error (502). This seems like a common issue that comes up, but none of the documentation online helped me. I tried setting up an API gateway, but that didn't seem to do anything. I included some more information in the original question about what my lambda function looks like. Let me know if you would like any more information!