# AWS Lambda: Invoke URL results in Bad Gateway (Error 502)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

(This is a follow-up to a previous post where I wanted to invoke a Lambda function from an unauthenticated user: [Invoke an AWS Lambda Function without being Authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77597525/invoke-an-aws-lambda-function-without-being-authenticated/77597596#77597596))

I'm attempting to invoke an AWS Lambda function by URL using the below Python code, but I am receiving an Internal Server Error (502: Bad Gateway) instead of a successful response:

```
import requests
from json import dumps

lambda_url = "https://[link].lambda-url.us-east-2.on.aws/"
response = requests.post(lambda_url, data=dumps(params))
return response
```

On the AWS side, I have a resource-based policy in place to allow InvokeFunctionURL from any source using AUTH_TYPE = NONE, shown in these images:
[Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1gC1.png) [Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZpm8.png) [JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRJcN.png)

The only thing I'm unsure if is needed or not is an API. From my understanding, you would call the API instead of the Lambda function, which doesn't seem correct. Regardless, I have one deployed, but it doesn't seem to be used in any part of the calls.

I apologize as my solution is probably in one of "Invoke Function" AWS documents (such as https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html), but I'm not finding anything indicating something wrong in my setup.

Let me know if there's any other information I can provide, and thank you so much for the help!

EDIT: Cleaning up the Lambda function so it now looks like this:
[Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekk4X.png)
[Function URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyqHP.png)

```
import json
from boto3 import client
from botocore import UNSIGNED
from botocore.client import Config

lambda_client = client('lambda', 
                aws_access_key_id='', 
                aws_secret_access_key='', 
                config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED),
                region_name="us-east-2")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName='TestInvokeFunction',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    )

    responseFromChild = json.load(response['Payload'])
    print('response', responseFromChild)

    return responseFromChild

lambda_handler({}, {})
```

With this version of the code, I receive a Missing Authentication Token error (breaks at lambda_client.invoke)

Answer (score 1):

You have two InvokeFunctionUrl policies. One in the Role of your Invoke Lambda and other created while creating Function URL. The one that is in your role seems incorrect due to which I think is failing. Remove that and keep only the one that is creating by default for you while creating Function URL.

Assuming that both of your lambdas are in the same region. I am creating 3 lambdas:

1. LambdaToInvoke: This will be invoked by the lambda that has function URL

```py
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(event)
    }
```

2. LambdaInvoker: The lambda that will invoke `LambdaToInvoke`. Also this lambda will be called via Function URL.

```py
import json
import boto3
client = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    event_body = event.get('body')
    
    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName='LambdaToInvoke',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=json.dumps(event_body)
    )

    response_json = json.load(response['Payload'])
    response_body_string = response_json.get('body')

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': response_body_string
    }
```

Allow `LambdaInvoker` to invoke `LambdaToInvoke` by adding `Allow: lambda:InvokeFunction` Action. ie attach the permission to `LambdaInvoker` function.

For function URL

1. Goto Configuration Tab of "Invoke Lambda"
2. Function URL option
3. Create Function URL
4. Select NONE as Auth Type
5. Save it (This will create proper policy for URL invocation)

Now LambdaInvoker will have InvokeFunction resource access for LambdaToInvoke and InvokeFunctionUrl in "Resource-based policy statements".

3. LambdaToHitAPI: This will hit the Function URL

```py
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = "https://[id].lambda-url.ap-south-1.on.aws/"
    
    data_dict = {"foo":"bar","kit":"kat"}
    json_string = json.dumps(data_dict)
    post_data = json_string.encode('utf-8')
    
    request = Request(url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}, data=post_data)
    with urlopen(request) as response:
        response = response.read()
        response_json = json.loads(response)
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': response_json
        }
        
    return 'Failed'
```

Notice that permissions are only required in one function, `LambdaInvoker`. Nothing is required in 1st and 3rd lambda.

Now when you run the lamda `LambdaToHitAPI`. This will hit the API to call the `LambdaInvoker`, and `LambdaInvoker` will call `LambdaToInvoke`.

Comment: Oh, good catch! Thank you for adding that. I should mention that method does result in a Missing Authentication Token error. I was curious if you knew why. (I also should mention that the functionName I'm passing in is "Artivox-IsAccount" as shown in the above Resource picture, but that doesn't feel correct).

Comment: You have InvokeFunctionUrl rule defined in 2 places. The one in your role seems to cause the issue. Remove that as the rule is created for you when you create Function URL (the one that you see Resource based policy statement. I have also updated by answer with an example.

Comment: I removed the duplicate InvokeFunctionURL. I am a bit confused though, as your code now indicates I shouldn't be invoking by URL anymore. I also could not make a boto3.client without providing a region and credentials. With your changes, I still do run into the Missing Authentication Token error, which seems not to be an issue with AWS but rather with boto3.

Comment: There was one thing I wasn't sure about how to do, when you said "Hit the API URL of Parent Lambda". What is the parent lambda in this case? Should I be making an API integration for this (and how), and by "hit", are you saying invoke? Just want to make sure I follow your instructions in whole, thank you for taking the time to help me through this!

Comment: Apologies for the confusion created. I have corrected the example. Do let me know if that's what you want to achieve. For boto client, let's say lambda X is invoking lambda Y then add permission in lambda X to invoke lambda Y as mentioned in the above example. Avoid using credentials as it can be risky. @joysterling